# Problem cloning from USB to SSD

Tags: system-installation, usb, cloning

I'm trying to build a mini server using an Intel NUC and a couple of external hard drives.

The challenge is I'm trying to do it completely headlessly (as my monitors and TV are about 5,000 miles away at the moment!). So far I've been able to create a bootable USB stick and can now log in to the server via SSH and Teamviewer, which is great.

The next step is to move the OS from the USB stick to the SSD installed in the NUC and I'm not sure how. I've seen lots of posts about cloning a drive, but they all involve running a Live CD which isn't much help on a headless system. One option might be to clone the USB stick to another USB stick, and then clone that new USB stick to the SSD whilst running on the old USB stick, but I thought I'd ask to see if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: I've now successfully got Ubuntu onto the SSD after using dd to clone the USB stick. I then booted from one stick, then used SSH and dd again to clone from the other USB stick to the SSD. Unfortunately something went wrong with Teamviewer along the way, so that's the next challenge!